# Hadith: Humans who became shaitan

Tags: hadith, source-identification

More than once I remember hearing a hadith that humans who follow Satan (those who commit all kinds of evil deeds intentionally) are actually worse than (more harmful to humans) than the Satan himself.

Am I recalling correctly? If so, what is the proper form of the hadith?